# Can't output debug info in vs2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, memory-leaks

Forgive my poor English.

I want check memory leak:

```
_CrtSetReportMode(_CRT_ASSERT, _CRTDBG_MODE_DEBUG);
_CrtSetReportMode(_CRT_WARN, _CRTDBG_MODE_DEBUG);
_CrtSetReportMode(_CRT_ERROR, _CRTDBG_MODE_DEBUG);
_CrtSetDbgFlag (_CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF);
```

when program exit I can't see any output in vs2012's debug output panel.

Then I step into _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks() and find there's memory leak and the leak check result is right but can't print out.

So I tried:

```
OutputDebugStringA("Output string");
```

VS still print nothing.

I tried **DebugView**, everything runs ok, but it's troublesome.

```
AllocConsole();
freopen("CONIN$", "r", stdin);
freopen("CONOUT$", "w", stdout);
freopen("CONOUT$", "w", stderr);
```

This can also work great.

Comment: Which programing language are you using exactly? Please provide an example with a simple main function, and memory allocations you use in your program, and the way you are set up the leak detection. Thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: @Richard First, language is C++,I set leak detection with `_CrtSetDbgFlag(_CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF);`
I tried even `int* pData = new int[100];` can't work.
But when I debug,`_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks()` has truely executed.

Answer (score 2):

You somehow got the VS debugger into a mode where it isn't displaying debug output, the kind that's generated by OutputDebugString().  Redirecting output to the Immediate window was covered so that can't be it.

There's really only one candidate left.  Right-click the Output window and ensure that the "Program Output" option is ticked.  This one:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Hans, Maybe you are right, The option is unchecked, so I checked it, but it still prints nothing. Any other help?

Comment: Seeing the option unchecked is 99.999% of an explanation.  You'll have to look for the other 0.001% elsewhere :)

Answer (score 0):

Solution given by Microsoft Connect:

Debug.WriteLine calls may not display in the output window if you have the Visual Studio option "Redirect all Output Window text to the Immediate Window" checked under the

**menu Tools > Options > Debugging > General. To display "Tools > Options > Debugging", check the box next to "Tools > Options > Show All Settings".**

Comment: I tried before.Neither check or uncheck that option, It can't work.

Answer (score 0):

A short example:

```
#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <crtdbg.h>

/*Your includes*/

#ifdef _DEBUG
  #ifndef DBG_NEW
    #define DBG_NEW new ( _NORMAL_BLOCK , __FILE__ , __LINE__ )
    #define new DBG_NEW
  #endif
#endif  // _DEBUG

#define SIZE 5

int main()
{
  _CrtSetDbgFlag ( _CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF );
  _CrtSetReportMode( _CRT_ERROR, _CRTDBG_MODE_DEBUG );

  int* myArrayCAlloc = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * SIZE);

  int* myArrayCppAlloc = new int[SIZE];

  return 0;
}
```

I think it works properly.

By the documentation of usage [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e5ewb1h3%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x98tx3cf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> This mapping occurs only in a debug build.

and

> If your program allocates memory using the C++ new operator, however, you need to redefine new.

by the following:

```
 #ifdef _DEBUG
     #ifndef DBG_NEW
         #define DBG_NEW new ( _NORMAL_BLOCK , __FILE__ , __LINE__ )
         #define new DBG_NEW
     #endif
 #endif  // _DEBUG
```

If you comment out the allocations from the example, you won't get any results on the Debug pane of the Output window.

Else I have gotten the following output:

> Detected memory leaks! 
>   Dumping objects ->
>   c:\users[user]\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\leak\main.cpp(23) : {78} normal block at 0x003E8A50, 20 bytes long.
>   Data: <                > CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD
>   c:\users[user]\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\leak\main.cpp(21) : {77} normal block at 0x003E9F80, 20 bytes long.
>   Data: <                > CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD
>   Object dump complete.

Also there is no output when you delete the allocated memory before the `return` statement:

```
  free(myArrayCAlloc);
  delete[] myArrayCppAlloc;
```

As you pointed out:

> When I debug,_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks() has truely executed

in the documentation:

> If your application does not define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC, _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks displays a memory-leak report

So you need to use `_CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC` if you would like to use `_CrtSetDbgFlag`, but this seems to be an indirect consequence of the reference.

Comment: Thanks @Richard, `_CRTDBG_MODE_FILE` can work, So I think my leak check settings is OK, and I checked your answer,I did everything you say.

Answer (score 0):

Please check

- is your solution set to run the Debug build?
- is your Debug configuration set to build a Debug build or a release build? Check in menu `Build / Configuration manager...`. It is possible that your solution is set to Debug mode, but still builds some projects in release mode.

[image: Screenshot of Debug configuration building reease mode project]

Comment: Thanks @Thomas, The solution it's Debug mode and every sub project is build in Build Mode.

Comment: If your problem is solved, would you please accept an answer? Thanks.

Comment: Currently unsolved. I think i can try to reinstall vs.